Signaling to Consumer that Producer has Stopped Producing
I have a console .NET Core application I am developing that gathers up data for emails and then sends those emails asynchronously using Channels.
I am currently adding the consumer as a hosted service so it can run in the background, very similarly to this example. My problem is that this app needs to run very infrequently, like once a week, and I don't want to leave it running all of the time if it's only doing 5 minutes of work or less at a time. But, I currently have no way to signal to the hosted consumer that the work is finished that I know of.
My question is: is there any way to create a "checkout divider" type of task to signal to the consumer to stop? or is there another way to stop the application automatically?
I am using .NET 8.0.

The ChannelWriter class (the one you use on the queueing side) has a Complete method that you can call to signal that the channel will not be receiving any more items.
You should call this method right after you add the last email on the channel for that "batch" of work.
If you combine that with something like the ReadAllAsync method on the ChannelReader side, it should stop iterating the IAsyncEnumerable once there are no more items in the channel, and you can exit the application at that point.
You'll likely have to inject something like IHostApplicationLifetime to gracefully stop the application from inside of the hosted service (the consumer), by calling StopApplication.
Here is a simple application that shows how this would work:
using System.Threading.Channels;

var channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();

var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
builder.Services
    .AddSingleton(TimeProvider.System)
    .AddHostedService(p => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Producer>(p, channel.Writer))
    .AddHostedService(p => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<Consumer>(p, channel.Reader));

var host = builder.Build();
await host.RunAsync();

internal sealed class Producer(ChannelWriter<string> channelWriter, TimeProvider timeProvider)
    : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await channelWriter.WriteAsync("item1", stoppingToken);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), timeProvider, stoppingToken);

        await channelWriter.WriteAsync("item2", stoppingToken);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), timeProvider, stoppingToken);

        await channelWriter.WriteAsync("item3", stoppingToken);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150), timeProvider, stoppingToken);

        channelWriter.Complete();
    }
}

internal sealed class Consumer(
    ChannelReader<string> channelReader, 
    IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await foreach (var text in channelReader.ReadAllAsync(stoppingToken))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received item `{text}`");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Received all items. Exiting...");
        appLifetime.StopApplication();
    }
}

You'll notice the 3 items will be printed, then the final message, and then the application will terminate normally.
